# Make event fire first... alternative to using $._data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a "confirm plugin" that will fire first and ask the user if "they are sure". Just to be clear, I will be using a custom-made confirm box, not the default Window confirm() Method.

If yes then it will fire all the other events that have been bound to it. If no then it will do nothing.

A use case would be a delete button that has a separate click event bound to it, which when pressed will delete an element.

If I attach my plugin to the button then it will bind another click event and by using the events info inside $._data I can send my even to the top of the list (making it fire first), I then stop propagation (this stops the other binding firing which deletes the element). If the user clicks ok on my confirm box, I trigger a click again this time just bypass the stop stuff and it will then fire the original events

I am using a slightly modified version of https://github.com/private-face/jquery.bind-first

The only way it can access this info on an element is by using:

```
$._data($(this)[0]).events
```

I want to know how "future proof" this is as I know this changed already since  1.7. Are there any plans to officially support a similar thing?

If all else fails, I know I can just make sure that the plugin and the bindings happen first in the code, but this is not really the most flexible solution.

Using $._data is a smelly solution, hence this post. Maybe there are some fancy custom event things I can do?

Comment: Using undocumented features should always be avoided.

Comment: The leading underscore suggests to me that the answer might be "not at all".

Comment: Also, this sounds like an XY problem. What is the event that you *need* to call first, and why do you need to do that?

Comment: As a side note, you could, depending your use-case, capture event to document level on browsers which support capturing phase: https://jsfiddle.net/resLgpek/

Comment: Why not just add a callback param inside of the confirm popup that triggers only when the user clicks 'OK'?

Comment: @BenM I can do that of course, but my big thing here is, how do I get the event (the confirm popup) to fire first, and stop propagation down to the other events until the callback is made. I want the plugin to be as generic as possible. ie.. calling the plugin from anywhere in the code will still make sure the binding happens first.

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/feature-request-public-event-listener-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and simple answer is *not at all*. Using, or more importantly *relying on* undocumented features is never a good idea.

It sounds like you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. There are likely many other ways to achieve what you're trying to do here, and using `$._data` is almost certainly **not** the best solution.